# Gnome instead of Ubuntu default desktop environement

Tags: desktop-environments

I've created a new standard use account, but it logs in only in GNOME. How can I change to Ubuntu default desktop environment?
The old user works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the login screen, it should be possible to choose between Gnome and Unity. There is a small icon that appears on one side of the username/password box.

Comment: I had GDM instead of LightDM. I change the login manager and it is OK. I accept your answer even if it is still not clear for me in GDM.

Comment: @DumitruCristian In GDM, there's a small gear icon next to the login button which lists sessions.

Comment: GDM does have a bit to change with desktop to use - e.g. like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2pF.png), or under a menu called 'session'.